# Какие Русские курсы для изучение React лучшие?

Tags: reactjs

Подскажите курсы для изучение Reactа на русском языке. Желательно от основ( знания JS есть, именно основ React,а ) до создание действительно нужных приложений. Курсов много, хочется узнать мнения действительно нужных курсов

Comment: От LoftSchool хорошие курсы. Нативный JS вообще очень крутой. По Реакту тоже неплох. С самых основ и до создания приложений с дипломной работой на выбор :)

Comment: как по мне - так в целом реакт не нужен, как и все остальные инфраструктурные фреймворки :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот здесь прям основы https://ru.reactjs.org/. Также есть хорошая книга "React и Redux Функциональная веб-разработка".